# Replace file paths with content of files

Tags: python, json, regex

I have a json file with a bunch of file paths in it. I want to write a script to replace all those file paths with the contents of the file that the path points to.

For example there is a file:

```
{
    "a": "stuff",
    "b: {
       "body": "/stack/over/flow/file.json"
    },
    "c": {
        "b": "stuff",
        "body": "here is some plain text"
    }
}
```

Then the file `/stack/over/flow/file.json` is:

```
{
    "another": "json"
}
```

and the output file would replace `/stack/over/flow/file.json` with the contents of that file. Also, since it is a json file, I need to do the proper escapes for it.

So there are really two things I need:

1. Replace file paths with contents of the file. I think a regex would be most useful here.
2. Adding the proper escapes to the json, so that it can be sent as the body of another json. I was thinking to use pythons json.dumps for this.

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this, or if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: You have invalid json in first snippet.

Comment: SO is not a 'code this for me' website … but maybe someone is interested in doing this for you ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP asks for code he hasn't even started.

Comment: Maybe parsing the JSON file into a dictionary and then accessing the value of body is the easier approach since you would have to read and write the file anyway.

Comment: @Alfe where did I say that I wanted anyone to write code for me? I simply was asking for guidance on if my approach I stated is a good one, and if people had any suggestions.

Comment: @user3408657 You may call it otherwise but you have no code and state the specs here. While that's clear and interesting (and my fingers even twitched), that's not the kind of questions approved on on SO.  No hard feelings, it's just the way the rules are around here to avoid SO becoming a list of example implementations of very specific tasks.  SO strives for being a collection of *generally* useful questions instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the json file, parse it (`json.load()`), and receive a structure (dictionary, list, string, or number).  This structure you need to tree-traverse (I propose a recursive function for this) and for every found leaf which resembles a link to another file, do the same recursively, and replace the link with the computed contents.

And pray that you do not have circular dependencies! ;-))